# Calculating incremental values from a cumulative sum field in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, common-table-expression, olap, teradatasql

Good afternoon -

I have a table in Teradata that stores a rolling cumulative sum that resets every month. I would like to be able to calculate the incremental gain between each day of the month. Is this something that I can accomplish with olap functions or should it be handled in a recursive cte? Would love assistance thinking through this. Thanks!

example source

| date | month | cum_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-02 | July 2022 | 25 |
| 2022-07-01 | July 2022 | 5 |
| 2022-06-30 | June 2022 | 100 |
| 2022-06-29 | June 2022 | 70 |
| 2022-06-28 | June 2022 | 65 |
| 2022-06-27 | June 2022 | 50 |

example result

| date | month | cum_value | incremental_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-02 | July 2022 | 25 | 20 |
| 2022-07-01 | July 2022 | 5 | 5 |
| 2022-06-30 | June 2022 | 100 | 30 |
| 2022-06-29 | June 2022 | 70 | 5 |
| 2022-06-28 | June 2022 | 65 | 15 |
| 2022-06-27 | June 2022 | 50 | .. |

Comment: `cum_value - lag(cum_value, 1, 0) over (partition by month order by date)`

Comment: Or if you do want null for the initial row: `cum_value - lag(cum_value,) over (partition by month order by date)